# NodeJs Get Accesskey Secret key and Session Token from federated identity pool

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am not able to get the access and secret keys and session token using aws.config.credentials.get() method. I have everything above this like authentication and roles working.

```
AWS.Config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                IdentityPoolId: poolid,
                'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_aWAJIClAA' : result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
            });
            console.log("Config.credentials "+ AWS.Config.credentials);

            AWS.Config.credentials.get(function () {
                console.log("credentials called ", AWS.Config.credentials);
                // Credentials will be available when this function is called.

                console.log("Access Key" + AWS.Config.credentials.accessKeyId );

                console.log("Secret Key" + AWS.Config.credentials.secretAccessKey );

                console.log("Session Token" + AWS.Config.credentials.sessionToken );
```

Comment: You need to pass the token inside the Login parameter while initializing CognitoIdentityCredentials. You have passed the token directly. It should be  new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({ IdentityPoolId: poolid,Logins: {'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_aWAJIClAA' : result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()}});

Comment: See this link for details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get `session` variable once the user is logged in using `user.getSession(callback)`

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const authenticator = `cognito-idp.${process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.REACT_APP_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}`
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId : process.env.IDENTITY_POOL_ID, 
    Logins : {
             [authenticator]: session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
    }
});
```